# function variables not assigning from mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, function

There are no full instructions on how to ask questions with code for stackoverflow.  The how to format is to basic.  Just says to indent code by 4 spaces.  I put the three single line snippets below and indent and it says the code is formatted wrong.

Why does this not work?

```
$sql = "SELECT uniqueToTime('$id') INTO @temp";
```

This below runs the select to the server.  Like to show it but overflow blocks the post.  Maybe it will show here by breaking the code

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn4, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn4));
```

Only prints temp not the value in temp from the assignment below.

```
$test = @temp;
```

Comment: before every single line in the code put  4 space.

Comment: PHP has no clue what `@temp` is. It resides in the connection memory area of mysql